# Spring WebClient - SOAP Encoder UnsupportedOperationException: null

Tags: java, soap, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am getting a UnsupportedOperationException: null on [Encoder.encodeValue() [spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/codec/Encoder.html#encodeValue-T-org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferFactory-org.springframework.core.ResolvableType-org.springframework.util.MimeType-java.util.Map-) when making a POST to a SOAP service using WebClient from Spring WebFlux.

I am using spring-boot 2.2.0.RELEASE with JDK 1.8.0_252 (application has requirement to use this for compatibility reasons). The application also has a requirement to be able to run synchronously, but we are evaluating replacing a blocking WebClient from our old RestTemplate and WebServiceTemplate to have a standard way to make web requests since RestTemplate is now in maintenance only mode. The calls I made with WebClient replacing RestTemplate work as expected, I just need to fix this error to handle the replacing of the WebServiceTemplate.

I setup the encoder and decoder with the clientCodecConfigurer object, but I can't seem to see the source of the code processing the Encoder.encodeValue() interface method. It doesn't look like it is going into the encoder I have setup, so I can't trace where the null value is coming from or why it is coming. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
2023-06-28T10:03:31.974-0400 DEBUG SpringService.rsa.RSAClient:42 - Making SOAP request to https://{soap.url}:{soap.port}/AdaptiveAuthentication/services/AdaptiveAuthentication 30
2023-06-28T10:03:31.974-0400 INFO SpringService.rsa.RSAClient:132 - Making analyze request now
2023-06-28T10:03:32.047-0400 INFO SpringService.config.WebClientConfig:99 - WebClient request: POST https://{soap.url}:{soap.port}/AdaptiveAuthentication/services/AdaptiveAuthentication org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters$$Lambda$709/1296999056@320c5ef8
2023-06-28T10:03:32.051-0400 DEBUG SpringService.config.WebClientConfig:101 - Header: Content-Type: text/xml
2023-06-28T10:03:32.111-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector:129 - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
2023-06-28T10:03:32.111-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector:130 - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
2023-06-28T10:03:32.147-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll:249 - Default Epoll support : true
2023-06-28T10:03:32.149-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopKQueue:249 - Default KQueue support : false
2023-06-28T10:03:32.159-0400 DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup:44 - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
2023-06-28T10:03:32.179-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap:54 - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
2023-06-28T10:03:32.179-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap:57 - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
2023-06-28T10:03:32.195-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent:890 - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
2023-06-28T10:03:32.239-0400 DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions:91 - [73ba4b0e] HTTP POST https://{soap.url}:{soap.port}/AdaptiveAuthentication/services/AdaptiveAuthentication
2023-06-28T10:03:32.258-0400 DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl:124 - netty-tcnative not in the classpath; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable.
2023-06-28T10:03:32.307-0400 DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext:96 - Default protocols (JDK): [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1] 
2023-06-28T10:03:32.308-0400 DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext:97 - Default cipher suites (JDK): [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
2023-06-28T10:03:32.323-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider:254 - Creating new client pool [http-client] for {soap.url}:{soap.port}
2023-06-28T10:03:32.353-0400 DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId:79 - -Dio.netty.processId: 1351120 (auto-detected)
2023-06-28T10:03:32.355-0400 DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId:101 - -Dio.netty.machineId: 00:50:56:ff:fe:9e:25:8d (auto-detected)
2023-06-28T10:03:32.382-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:142 - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 4
2023-06-28T10:03:32.382-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:143 - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 4
2023-06-28T10:03:32.382-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:145 - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
2023-06-28T10:03:32.382-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:150 - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
2023-06-28T10:03:32.382-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:154 - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
2023-06-28T10:03:32.382-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:155 - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
2023-06-28T10:03:32.383-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:156 - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
2023-06-28T10:03:32.383-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:157 - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
2023-06-28T10:03:32.383-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:158 - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
2023-06-28T10:03:32.383-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:159 - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
2023-06-28T10:03:32.383-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:160 - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
2023-06-28T10:03:32.383-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:161 - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
2023-06-28T10:03:32.383-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator:162 - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
2023-06-28T10:03:32.391-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil:85 - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
2023-06-28T10:03:32.392-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil:94 - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
2023-06-28T10:03:32.392-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil:97 - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
2023-06-28T10:03:32.408-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider:254 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88] Created new pooled channel, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2023-06-28T10:03:32.432-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf:62 - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
2023-06-28T10:03:32.432-0400 DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf:63 - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
2023-06-28T10:03:32.434-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory:195 - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@3cf5a5a0
2023-06-28T10:03:32.442-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider:254 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88] SSL enabled using engine SSLEngineImpl and SNI {soap.url}:{soap.port}
2023-06-28T10:03:32.447-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers:254 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.sslReader = reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler), (BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2023-06-28T10:03:32.458-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider:254 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443] Channel connected, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2023-06-28T10:03:32.464-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler:96 - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
2023-06-28T10:03:32.464-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler:97 - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2023-06-28T10:03:32.464-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler:98 - -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2023-06-28T10:03:32.464-0400 DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler:99 - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
2023-06-28T10:03:32.536-0400 DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler:1748 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2023-06-28T10:03:32.537-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider:254 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443]}, [connected])
2023-06-28T10:03:32.539-0400 INFO SpringService.config.WebClientConfig:118 - WebClient State Change: connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443]}, newState=[connected]
2023-06-28T10:03:32.555-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider:254 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443] onStateChange(GET{uri=/, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443]}}, [configured])
2023-06-28T10:03:32.556-0400 INFO SpringService.config.WebClientConfig:118 - WebClient State Change: connection=GET{uri=/, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443]}}, newState=[configured]
2023-06-28T10:03:32.557-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect:254 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443] Handler is being applied: {uri=https://{soap.url}:{soap.port}/AdaptiveAuthentication/services/AdaptiveAuthentication, method=POST}
2023-06-28T10:03:32.570-0400 DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations:259 - [id: 0x8f0f4d88, L:/{host.ip}:36508 - R:{soap.url}/{soap.ip}:8443] Outbound error happened
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.springframework.core.codec.Encoder.encodeValue(Encoder.java:89) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.EncoderHttpMessageWriter.lambda$write$1(EncoderHttpMessageWriter.java:125) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) [reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) [reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2148) [reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1956) [reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1830) [reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) [reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55) [reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) [reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:430) [reactor-netty-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:473) [reactor-netty-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:525) [reactor-netty-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:434) [reactor-netty-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelActive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:62) [reactor-netty-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.0.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:225) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:211) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:204) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:414) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelActive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:69) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:213) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:225) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:211) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:204) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler.userEventTriggered(SslProvider.java:731) [reactor-netty-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.0.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:327) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeSuccess(SslHandler.java:1750) [netty-handler-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1409) [netty-handler-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1224) [netty-handler-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1271) [netty-handler-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505) [netty-codec-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444) [netty-codec-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283) [netty-codec-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) [netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.42.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:483) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.42.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:383) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.42.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044) [netty-common-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.42.Final.jar!/:4.1.42.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
```

I have a @Configuration class: WebClientConfig implements ConnectionObserver, with the following Beans:

```
@Bean("httpClient")
HttpClient httpClient() {
    ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.fixed("http-client",
            settings.getMaxConnections(),
            settings.getAcquireTimeout(),
            Duration.ofMillis(settings.getMaxIdleTime()));
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(connectionProvider)
            .observe(this);
    log.debug("connectionProvider: {}, httpClient: {}", connectionProvider, httpClient);
    return httpClient;
}

@Bean("soapWebClient")
WebClient soapWebClient() {
    ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> {
            clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().encoder(new Jaxb2SoapEncoder());
            clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().decoder(new Jaxb2SoapDecoder());
            log.debug("clientCodecConfigurer: {}", clientCodecConfigurer);
            log.debug("customCodecs: {}", clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs());
        }).build();

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient()))
        .filter(this.logRequest())
        .filter(this.logResponse())
        .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
        .build();

    log.debug("exchangeStrategies: {}, webClient: {}", exchangeStrategies, webClient);
    return webClient;
}
```

class: Jaxb2SoapDecoder extends Jaxb2XmlDecoder

```
private static final XMLInputFactory inputFactory = StaxUtils.createDefensiveInputFactory();

private final JaxbContextContainer jaxbContexts = new JaxbContextContainer();

public Jaxb2SoapDecoder() {
    super();
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked", "cast"})  // XMLEventReader is Iterator<Object> on JDK 9
public Object decode(DataBuffer dataBuffer, ResolvableType targetType,
                     @Nullable MimeType mimeType, @Nullable Map<String, Object> hints) throws DecodingException {
    try {
        DefaultStrategiesHelper helper = new DefaultStrategiesHelper(WebServiceTemplate.class);
        WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory = helper.getDefaultStrategy(WebServiceMessageFactory.class);
        WebServiceMessage message = messageFactory.createWebServiceMessage( dataBuffer.asInputStream() );
        return unmarshal(message, targetType.toClass());
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex = (ex.getCause() instanceof XMLStreamException ? ex.getCause() : ex);
        throw Exceptions.propagate(ex);
    }
    finally {
        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
    }
}

private Object unmarshal(WebServiceMessage message, Class<?> outputClass) {
    try {
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = initUnmarshaller(outputClass);
        JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getPayloadSource(),outputClass);
        return jaxbElement.getValue();
    }
    catch (UnmarshalException ex) {
        throw new DecodingException("Could not unmarshal XML to " + outputClass, ex);
    }
    catch (JAXBException ex) {
        throw new CodecException("Invalid JAXB configuration", ex);
    }
}

private Unmarshaller initUnmarshaller(Class<?> outputClass) throws CodecException, JAXBException {
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = this.jaxbContexts.createUnmarshaller(outputClass);
    return getUnmarshallerProcessor().apply(unmarshaller);
}
```

class: Jaxb2SoapEncoder implements Encoder

```
private final JaxbContextContainer jaxbContexts = new JaxbContextContainer();

@Override
public boolean canEncode(ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType) {
    Class<?> outputClass = elementType.toClass();
    return (outputClass.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class) ||
            outputClass.isAnnotationPresent(XmlType.class));
}

@Override
public Flux<DataBuffer> encode(Publisher<?> inputStream, DataBufferFactory bufferFactory, ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType, Map<String, Object> hints) {
    return Flux.from(inputStream)
            .take(1)
            .concatMap(value -> encode(value, bufferFactory, elementType, mimeType, hints))
            .doOnDiscard(PooledDataBuffer.class, PooledDataBuffer::release);
}

@Override
public List<MimeType> getEncodableMimeTypes() {
    return Arrays.asList( MimeTypeUtils.TEXT_XML );
}

private Flux<DataBuffer> encode(Object value ,
                                DataBufferFactory bufferFactory,
                                ResolvableType type,
                                MimeType mimeType,
                                Map<String, Object> hints){
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        boolean release = true;
        DataBuffer buffer = bufferFactory.allocateBuffer(1024);
        try {
            SoapEnvelopeRequest soapEnvelopeRequest = (SoapEnvelopeRequest)value;

            OutputStream outputStream = buffer.asOutputStream();
            Class<?> clazz = ClassUtils.getUserClass(soapEnvelopeRequest.getBody());
            Marshaller marshaller = initMarshaller(clazz);

            DefaultStrategiesHelper helper = new DefaultStrategiesHelper(WebServiceTemplate.class);
            WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory = helper.getDefaultStrategy(WebServiceMessageFactory.class);
            WebServiceMessage message = messageFactory.createWebServiceMessage();

            if( soapEnvelopeRequest.getHeaderContent() != null ){
                SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage)message;
                SoapHeader header = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
                StringSource headerSource = new StringSource(soapEnvelopeRequest.getHeaderContent());
                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                transformer.transform(headerSource, header.getResult());
            }

            marshaller.marshal(soapEnvelopeRequest.getBody(), message.getPayloadResult());
            message.writeTo(outputStream);

            release = false;
            return buffer;
        }
        catch (MarshalException ex) {
            throw new EncodingException(
                    "Could not marshal " + value.getClass() + " to XML", ex);
        }
        catch (JAXBException ex) {
            throw new CodecException("Invalid JAXB configuration", ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (release) {
                DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
            }
        }
    }).flux();
}

private Marshaller initMarshaller(Class<?> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    Marshaller marshaller = this.jaxbContexts.createMarshaller(clazz);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return marshaller;
}
```

class: JaxbContextContainer

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Class<?>, JAXBContext> jaxbContexts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(64);


public Marshaller createMarshaller(Class<?> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = getJaxbContext(clazz);
    return jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
}

public Unmarshaller createUnmarshaller(Class<?> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = getJaxbContext(clazz);
    return jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
}

private JAXBContext getJaxbContext(Class<?> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    Assert.notNull(clazz, "Class must not be null");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = this.jaxbContexts.get(clazz);
    if (jaxbContext == null) {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        this.jaxbContexts.putIfAbsent(clazz, jaxbContext);
    }
    return jaxbContext;
}
```

And when I make the request:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("soapWebClient")
WebClient soapWebClient;

public <I, O> O marshalSendAndReceive(String soapServiceUrl, I request, Class<I> requestClass, Class<O> responseClass) {
    log.debug("Making SOAP request to {} {}", soapServiceUrl, log.isTraceEnabled() ? String.valueOf(request) : String.valueOf(request).length());
    return soapWebClient.post()
        .uri(soapServiceUrl)
        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
        .body(Mono.just(request), requestClass)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse ->
            clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(errorResponseBody -> {
                log.error("Fault from SOAP call {} {} {}", soapServiceUrl, clientResponse.statusCode(), errorResponseBody);
                return Mono.error(new ResponseStatusHeadersException(
                    clientResponse.statusCode(),
                    clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders(),
                    errorResponseBody
                ));
            })
        )
        .bodyToMono(responseClass)
        .block();
}

public AnalyzeResponse analyze(Analyze request) {
    log.info("RSAClient - Processing the analyze request:" + request.toString());
    log.info("Making analyze request now");
    
    AnalyzeResponse response = null;
    response = marshalSendAndReceive(settings.getRsaEntServerAddress(), request, Analyze.class, AnalyzeResponse.class);
    
    log.info("Successfully got analyze response: {}", response);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find and fix my problem. Checking the javadocs some more, encodeValue() by default raises UnsupportedOperationException as it is expected that some encoders cannot produce a single buffer or cannot do so synchronously (e.g. encoding a Resource).

So, I redid these classes:

class Jaxb2RsaDecoder extends Jaxb2XmlDecoder

```
public Jaxb2RsaDecoder() {
    super();
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked", "cast"})  // XMLEventReader is Iterator<Object> on JDK 9
public Object decode(DataBuffer dataBuffer, ResolvableType targetType,
                     @Nullable MimeType mimeType, @Nullable Map<String, Object> hints) throws DecodingException {
    log.debug("dataBuffer: {}, targetType: {}", dataBuffer, targetType);
    try {
        DefaultStrategiesHelper helper = new DefaultStrategiesHelper(WebServiceTemplate.class);
        WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory = helper.getDefaultStrategy(WebServiceMessageFactory.class);
        WebServiceMessage message = messageFactory.createWebServiceMessage( dataBuffer.asInputStream() );
        return unmarshal(message, targetType.toClass());
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex = (ex.getCause() instanceof XMLStreamException ? ex.getCause() : ex);
        throw Exceptions.propagate(ex);
    }
    finally {
        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
    }
}

private Object unmarshal(WebServiceMessage message, Class<?> outputClass) {
    log.debug("message: {}, outputClass: {}", message, outputClass);
    try {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = initJaxb2Marshaller();
        Object value = marshaller.unmarshal(message.getPayloadSource());
        log.debug("value.class: {}, outputClass: {}", value.getClass(), outputClass);
        return value;
    }
    catch (UnmarshalException ex) {
        throw new DecodingException("Could not unmarshal XML to " + outputClass, ex);
    }
    catch (JAXBException ex) {
        throw new CodecException("Invalid JAXB configuration", ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new DecodingException("Could not unmarshal XML to " + outputClass, ex);
    }
}

private Jaxb2Marshaller initJaxb2Marshaller() throws JAXBException {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath(settings.getRsaPackage());

    try {
        marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not set properties, please check ", e);
    }

    getUnmarshallerProcessor().apply(marshaller.createUnmarshaller());

    return marshaller;
}
```

class Jaxb2RsaEncoder implements Encoder

```
@Override
public boolean canEncode(ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType) {
    Class<?> outputClass = elementType.toClass();
    boolean result = (outputClass.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class) ||
                      outputClass.isAnnotationPresent(XmlType.class));
    log.debug("outputClass: {}, canEncode: {}", outputClass, result);
    return result;
}

@Override
public Flux<DataBuffer> encode(Publisher<?> inputStream, DataBufferFactory bufferFactory, ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType, Map<String, Object> hints) {
    return Flux.from(inputStream)
            .take(1)
            .concatMap(value -> encode(value, bufferFactory, elementType, mimeType, hints))
            .doOnDiscard(PooledDataBuffer.class, PooledDataBuffer::release);
}

@Override
public List<MimeType> getEncodableMimeTypes() {
    return Arrays.asList( MediaType.TEXT_XML );
}

private Flux<DataBuffer> encode(Object value,
                                DataBufferFactory bufferFactory,
                                ResolvableType type,
                                MimeType mimeType,
                                Map<String, Object> hints) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> this.encodeValue(value, bufferFactory, type, mimeType, hints)).flux();
}

@Override
public DataBuffer encodeValue(Object value, DataBufferFactory bufferFactory, ResolvableType type,
                              @Nullable MimeType mimeType, @Nullable Map<String, Object> hints) {
    log.debug("encodeValue - start: {}", value.getClass());
    boolean release = true;
    DataBuffer buffer = bufferFactory.allocateBuffer(1024);
    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = buffer.asOutputStream();
        Class<?> clazz = ClassUtils.getUserClass(value);
        Marshaller marshaller = initJaxb2Marshaller().createMarshaller();

        // here should be optimized
        DefaultStrategiesHelper helper = new DefaultStrategiesHelper(WebServiceTemplate.class);
        WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory = helper.getDefaultStrategy(WebServiceMessageFactory.class);
        WebServiceMessage message = messageFactory.createWebServiceMessage();

        marshaller.marshal(value, message.getPayloadResult());
        message.writeTo(outputStream);

        release = false;
        log.debug("encodeValue - buffer: {}", buffer);
        return buffer;
    } catch (MarshalException ex) {
        throw new EncodingException("Could not marshal " + value.getClass() + " to XML", ex);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        throw new CodecException("Invalid JAXB configuration", ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new EncodingException("Could not encode value " + value.getClass() + " to XML", ex);
    } finally {
        if (release) {
            DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
        }
    }
}


private Jaxb2Marshaller initJaxb2Marshaller() throws JAXBException {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath(settings.getRsaPackage());

    try {
        marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not set properties, please check ", e);
    }

    return marshaller;
}
```

And then updated the ExchangeStrategy on the webClient:

```
@Bean("soapWebClient")
WebClient soapWebClient() {
    ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> {
            Encoder<Object> encoder = new Jaxb2RsaEncoder();
            clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().encoder(encoder);
            Decoder<Object> decoder = new Jaxb2RsaDecoder();
            clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().decoder(decoder);
            log.debug("clientCodecConfigurer: {}", clientCodecConfigurer);
            log.debug("customCodecs: {}", clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs());
            log.debug("encoder: {}, decoder: {}", encoder, decoder);
        }).build();

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient()))
        .filter(this.logRequest())
        .filter(this.logResponse())
        .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
        .build();

    log.debug("exchangeStrategies: {}, webClient: {}", exchangeStrategies, webClient);
    return webClient;
}
```

Now, I can make synchronous requests and the exchange strategy will use my WSDL generated packages to handle encoding and decoding of the SOAP classes.